# Encontrar en un List todas las posiciones del elemento buscado, si es que hay mas de uno c#

Tags: c#, lista

Estoy intentando listar todos los promedios mas altos de una lista de promedios. Necesito saber la posición(índice) o posiciones(índices) de esas coincidencias.

```
   List<float>promedios = {6, 6.5, 7, 8, 9, 9};
   public static List<float> mejoresAlumnos(List<float> listaPromedios) 
    {                var mayor = listaPromedios.Max();
                     //Código faltante
                     return result;
    }
```

Tendría que obtener `List<float>result = {4, 5}`
que son las posiciones(índices) de los números mas altos de la lista

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuáles serían los más altos? ¿Los tres mayores? ¿Sólo dos? ¿Qué significaría *__todos__ los promedios más altos*? Hace falta más información en tu pregunta para poder ayudarte. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Saludos

Comment: Seguí tus recomendaciones y agregue más información

Comment: Y qué pasa si hay un empate a cuatro? Es decir, cuatro alumnos obtienen el mismo promedio, ¿qué índices esperarías obtener?

Comment: Espero obtener todos los índices que coinciden con el mayor valor.

Comment: Esto no es posible, es diferente un ArrayList y un Array :  List<float>promedios = {6, 6.5, 7, 8, 9, 9};

Comment: Ya casi lo tenes.. si tenes el maximo, con recorrer la lista y guardar cada indice que coincida con el maximo, ya esta... probaste eso?

Comment: Igual, si queres indices, tu metodo deberia devolver una List<int>... los indices son enteros, no float....

Comment: Es cierto, ya lo tenia. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtuve todos de los índices de la lista que coinciden con el Max() con esto:

```
    public static List<float> indiceMejoresPromedios(List<float> listaPromedios)
    {
          List<int> resultado = new List<int>();
          var mayor = listaPromedios.Max();
        for (int i = 0; i < listaPromedios.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listaPromedios[i] == mayor)
            {
                resultado.Add(i);
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Gracias. Seguramente se puede mejorar.

Comment: bueno.. ahora saca el max de adentro del if.. el max es siempre el mismo.. No devuelvas una lista de float, los indices son int.